# how to run a local docker registry inside a docker container

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-registry, cicd

I am trying to run a process in gitlab ci that mimics the clients use case to make sure our modifications do not disrupt their use case. This is the specific job that is failing.

```
docker-source:
  stage: build
  image: carlallen/docker:buildx
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
      command: ["dockerd", "--host=tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"]
      alias: 'docker'
  script:
    - echo "Building..."
    - docker --version
    - docker buildx
    - docker buildx create --use --config buildkit.toml --driver-opt network=host --buildkitd-flags '--allow-insecure-entitlement security.insecure --allow-insecure-entitlement network.host' --name test_name
    - docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
    - ./build-docker.sh

$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.14, build 5eb3275
$ docker buildx
Usage:  docker buildx [OPTIONS] COMMAND
Build with BuildKit
Options:
      --builder string   Override the configured builder instance
Management Commands:
  imagetools  Commands to work on images in registry
Commands:
  bake        Build from a file
  build       Start a build
  create      Create a new builder instance
  du          Disk usage
  inspect     Inspect current builder instance
  ls          List builder instances
  prune       Remove build cache 
  rm          Remove a builder instance
  stop        Stop builder instance
  use         Set the current builder instance
  version     Show buildx version information 
Run 'docker buildx COMMAND --help' for more information on a command.
$ docker buildx create --use --config buildkit.toml --driver-opt network=host --buildkitd-flags '--allow-insecure-entitlement security.insecure --allow-insecure-entitlement network.host' --name test_name
test_name
$ docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
docker: error during connect: Post http://docker:2375/v1.40/containers/create?name=registry: dial tcp: lookup docker on XXX.XX.X.X:53: no such host.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you show the output of running `docker info` from your build?

Answer (score 0):

Do not override the command or entrypoint for the `docker:dind` image. Use environment variables to control the behavior.

```yaml
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: 'docker'
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""  # disable tls, force use of port 2375
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker info  # verify connection/server details
```

If this doesn't work, then you are probably using a self-hosted runner that is not configured correctly for use with docker-in-docker. You should follow the [docker in docker guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html) and make sure you runner is setup according to the documentation.